# Localhost Wordpress Logo Image working well but not working in live host

Tags: php, xampp

I have Made a Wordpress CMS in Localhost through xammp Server. There have a logo image in WordPress Site. But the WordPress Logo image not work when I upload in the live server. In the local server the logo image is working well. Whats the reason about this manner?

Comment: did you uploaded logo image to live server ?

Comment: Did you change the reference url to the image? If it is still set to the local folder, then it can't find the image on the live server.